# Passing objects to functions and dynamic memory allocation in constructors

Tags: c++

I was given a homework to pass objects to member functions and to use constructor in C++ (Dynamic memory allocation must be followed to store values). Check the code given below.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class room
{
    char *a;
    public:
    room(string e)
    {
        a = new char[e.length()];
        string a(e);
    }
    friend void show(room);
};

void show(room z)
{
    cout << z.a;
}

int main()
{
    string c;
    cout << "Enter: ";
    cin >> c;
    room A(c);
    show(A);
}
```

Now, I want the string given as input must be printed by show() after compiling the code.

How to modify the code to get the output from show()??

Comment: Your code is totally broken. Take a step back and try to understand what each line in your constructor is doing. Then read up on [*the rule of three*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29).

Comment: `string a(e);` doesn't do what you think it does; it does **not** copy contents of `e` into buffer pointed to by member variable `a`. Instead, it declares a local variable named `a` of type `string`, completely unrelated to `room::a` member; copies contents of `e` into this local variable; then immediately destroys it. Contents of `room::a` buffer remain uninitialized garbage.

Comment: Consider `std::string a;` instead of `char *a;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems in your code :

- the member a is not initialized
- a copy constructor is used but not implemented : show(A) copy A
- the member a is not freed

Fixing this will give something like  :

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class room
{
    char *a;
    public:
    room(string e) : a(strdup(e.c_str())) {};
    room(const room &); // not implemented copy construtor
    room & operator=(const room &); // not implemented copy operator
    ~room() { free(a); };
    friend void show(const room &);
};

void show(const room & z)
{
    cout << z.a;
}

int main()
{
    string c;
    cout << "Enter: ";
    cin >> c;
    room A(c);
    show(A);
}
```

But as suggested in comments, using a std::string to store the value is a better alternative to the char*.